# Attach PDF to email using UIActivityViewController

Tags: ios, swift, swift2, ios9, uiactivityviewcontroller

I am using the UIActivityViewController to give the user options to share data from within my app. The data being shared are pdf files.

The pdf files are stored on the server, I perform a GET request to download the pdf file like so:

```
let sessionConfig = NSURLSessionConfiguration.defaultSessionConfiguration()
let session = NSURLSession(configuration: sessionConfig, delegate: nil, delegateQueue: nil)
let request = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: NSURL(string: userBioLink!)!)
request.HTTPMethod = "GET"
let task = session.dataTaskWithRequest(request, completionHandler: {data, response, err -> Void in
    print("THIS IS THE PDF \(data)")      
    print("Entered share bio function")
})
task.resume()
```

I am successfully downloading the pdf.
Next I want the user to have options to share this pdf. So I use this:

```
let activityItems = "Sharing data"
let actviewcon = UIActivityViewController(activityItems: activityItems , applicationActivities: nil)
self.presentViewController(actviewcon, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

The above also works well. 
But I want to be able to do the following:

1. **If user selects Email then the PDF is attached as an attachment**
2. **If the user selects message the URL of the pdf pasted as text in the message**

Can anyone help me here.
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

First of all convert the pdf file that you downloaded to NSData object.

For Example -

```
 NSData *noteData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:exe.pdf];
```

Then using the MFMailComposeViewController object '_mailController' call the below method

```
 [_mailController addAttachmentData:noteData mimeType:@"text/plain" fileName:@"exe.pdf"];
```

Hope this work.